# Differential map of polar decomposition projector.

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I'm reading sec 2.2 from this article  [Arxiv:2201.10768](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.10768.pdf) and there is part that I don't understand

Some context:
Let $A(t) \in GL(n)$ and consider its polar decomposition $A(t)=U(t)P(t)$, where $U(t) \in O(n)$ and $P(t)$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix. From this we can define a projector operator from $GL(n)$ to $O(n)$ via $\mathbb{P}(A):=U$. From orthogonality $U(t)U^T(t)=I$ follows that $\frac{dU}{dt} = U\Omega $, where $\Omega$ is a skew-symmetric matrix (Indeed, $\Omega =-U\frac{d}{dt} U^T U$).

Why the differential map of the projection operator is  $d\mathbb{P}_{A}(\dot{A})=\Omega$ ?
I tried by doing the following: Let consider a curve $A(t)$ with $A(0)=A$ and then
$$d\mathbb{P}_{A}(\dot{A})= \frac{d}{dt} (\mathbb{P} \circ A(t))|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt} (\mathbb{P}(A(t)))|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt} U(t) |_{t=0}= U(0)\Omega(0) $$

Of course my calculations are not coherent with $d\mathbb{P}_{A}(\dot{A})=\Omega$. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of $d\mathbb{P}_{A}(\dot{A})$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net according to the article, the tangent map of the projection operator $\mathbb{P}:GL(n) \to O(n)$.

Comment: But why the dot over $A$?

Comment: I suppose that is the current notation for differential maps on manifolds $d F_p(x'(0)) = (F\circ x)'(0)$ where $x(0)=p$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential). I did not write the article so I'm not really sure.